# Get public key bits in OSX from generated pair keys

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, encryption, cryptography

This method is used to get public key bits in iOS.

```
- (NSData *)getPublicKeyBits {
    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
    NSData * publicKeyBits = nil;

    NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Set the public key query dictionary.
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecClassKey forKey:(id)kSecClass];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)kSecReturnData];

    // Get the key bits.
    sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&publicKeyBits);

    if (sanityCheck != noErr)
    {
        publicKeyBits = nil;
    }

    [queryPublicKey release];

    return publicKeyBits;
}
```

But it works only in iOS not for OSX, for OSX  I need to use Security Transforms. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecTransformPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010801-CH1-SW1

I know how to generate pair public/private keys, and do it for iOS.

What kind of transform do I need to use in OSX to get public key bits from public key? To get the same effect as it it's in provided example for iOS.